# Logoff após editar uma Role do usuário

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Estou trabalhando em um projeto asp.net-mvc e gostaria forçar o logoff do usuário após editar uma role pertencente ao usuário, usando asp.net-identity

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var role = await RoleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        if (role == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        RoleViewModel roleModel = new RoleViewModel { Id = role.Id, Name = role.Name };
        return View(roleModel);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Roles/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]

    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "Name,Id")] RoleViewModel roleModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var role = await RoleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleModel.Id);
            role.Name = roleModel.Name;
            await RoleManager.UpdateAsync(role);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        var autheticationUser = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        autheticationUser.SignOut();
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Dá uma olhadinha na última resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766191/asp-net-identity-add-another-user-to-role-instantly-they-dont-have-to-log-out

Comment: Coloque o return RedirectToAction("Index"); no lugar de return View();

Comment: Fiz a alteração mas não redirecionou para Index

Answer (score 0):

Tente o trecho a seguir.

```
var autheticationUser = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
autheticationUser.SignOut();
```

Comment: Gostaria que logo apos editar uma role a aplicação fizesse o logoff do usuário

Comment: Você inseriu esse código na sua action logo depois da edição do role?

Comment: Inseri logo depois da edição do role

Comment: Coloque seu código na pergunta.

Comment: Modifiquei a pergunta